# How to get the Object key of the associated object in angularFire2?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I query the database by userkey to find if an associated object exists:

``` let url = ``/userMember/${userKey}``; ```

```
const userMemberRef = this.af.database.object(url, { preserveSnapshot: true });

userMemberRef.subscribe(data => {
  if(data.val()!=null) {
    console.log(data.val());
    memberKey= data.val();
  }
});
return memberKey;
```

It logs this in console which is good because the data I want is there.

`Object {-Ke2CyV2BJ5S3_7qcQj5: true}`

But how can I return the child key value "`-Ke2CyV2BJ5S3_7qcQj5`"?

Seems to be very trivial. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Here, the `subscribe` is asynchronous, so you are returning `memberKey` before it has a value assigned. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6847754/6680611

Comment: So what is the solution to get the value? I thought the subscribe will unwrap it. I need the value unwrap as it is needed by the consuming method.

Answer (score 1):

`data.val()` actually references the value of `userKey`. Since `userMember/${userKey}` is not a path to a key value pair but an object, the "value" of `userKey` is that object. If you want to assign the key of  a property of that object to a variable, you will need to map to the property's key.

Since it's safe to assume you can't predict what that key will be, there isn't a straightforward way to do this as far as I know. On the plus side there are a number of conceivable ways to do this. The important thing is that you understand the above.

The fact that you don't have a straightforward way to access this key and want to might be an indication that you should reconsider the structure of your model *if at all possible*.

I'll leave you with this example of how to "get at" the key, mostly to illustrate its relationship to the path you're using:

```
this.af.database.object(`userMember/${userKey}`)
.subscribe(member => console.log(Object.keys(member)[0]));
```

Comment: the syntax that works for me is `console.log(Object.keys(member.val())[0]);`

Comment: I assume because you're using `preserveSnapshot`. Did you try to log the keys without it?

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
const key = object['$key'];
```

Comment: BANG! you a boss :D this is imho the most elegant solution